# Wrap letters in string with spans

Tags: javascript

I've been challenging myself to write more JS. Now I have this simple challenge which is just to wrap all the letters in a heading with spans.

When I console log spanWrap it seems to output the correct results but I can't seem to push it into the heading dynamically. Any ideas? Yes,

```js
'use strict';

let i, spanWrap = "";

const string = document.getElementById('heading');
console.log(string);

function span() {

  for (let i = 0; i < string.innerText.length; i++) {
    if (string.innerText[i] !== " ") {
      const spanWrap = `<span>` + string.innerText[i] + `</span>`;
      console.log(spanWrap);
    }
  }

  string.innerHTML = spanWrap;
};

span();
```

```html
<h1 id='heading'>Test</h1>
```

I've done a lot of searching and even references a few SO answers but the point is to understand and learn this instead of just copying/pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new variable named spanWrap inside the loop. Since it is in a block determined by `{}` it is a different scope than the outer variable with same name and shadows the outer one.

Add to existing one with `+=` instead of creating a new version.

You also need an `else` in order to put back any spaces

```js
   

const string = document.getElementById('heading');    

function span() {
  let  spanWrap = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < string.innerText.length; i++) {
    if (string.innerText[i] !== " ") {
      spanWrap += `<span>` + string.innerText[i] + `</span>`;
      // ^^ concatenate outer scope spanWrap
      console.log(spanWrap);
    }else{
        spanWrap += ' ';// add the spaces back 
     }
  }

  string.innerHTML = spanWrap;
};

span();
```

```css
#heading span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<h1 id='heading'>Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate spanWrap.

```js
'use strict';

let i, spanWrap = "";

const string = document.getElementById('heading');
console.log(string);

function span() {
let spanWrap = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < string.innerText.length; i++) {
        if(string.innerText[i] !== " ") {
            spanWrap += `<span class="red">` + string.innerText[i] + `</span>`;
            console.log(spanWrap);
        }
    }
    
    string.innerHTML = spanWrap;
};

span();
```

```css
.red{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='heading'>Test</h1>
```